# Unread/Read and decrease Notification Badges in webpage

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, notifications

I'm trying to have a notification badges (web-based) that can read and unread, and also decrease, imagine gmail notification, when you click a certain mail the notification badge will decrease permanently unless it is was increased, what I need is that, if I click a certain button, the notification badge will decrease permanently or disappear if the notification is only one.

Here's what we got so far..

```html
<a class='btn btn-default btn-xs' href='#' role='button' id="view-notification">View Notification</a>

<a href="index.php?cat=notifications">Notifications<span class="badge" id="notification-badge">7</span></a>
```

also this one

[click me](http://jsfiddle.net/utdhx2Lg/)

The javascript function only allows to hide the notification badge